# Suggested edits pending bubble displays even when it is your own pending edit

Tags: bug, feature-request

I suggested an edit and now the little bubble is showing that there is 1 suggested edit pending. Since I was the one who suggested the edit, I of course can not approve the edit. When I click on the bubble it tells me there are no pending edits, the bubble should reflect this as well.

Comment: Very good point - we'll either filter the header count or just show you your suggested edit in the queue without any action buttons.  This will depend on database cost, which the mighty [Waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) will look into.